# Only show <php "the_field()" ?> if it has a specifik value

Tags: php, wordpress

So, i was wondering if there's a way to target a specific value in a `<?php the_field('title'); ?>` loop.

I'm iterating over a result set of people on a site. If `title` equals `CEO` it should display in another row.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Personal
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main" class="fullpage" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fullpagebg.png);">

<section class="banner innerBanner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bannerContent">
            <h1>Vår <strong>personal</strong></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    
<section class="padtop0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="productsMain">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
<?php   
    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'Persons') );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                                    
                    <div class="personalbox" style="background-color: #f3f3f3; background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('bild'); ?>); background-size: <?php echo $background_size; ?>;">
                        <div class="personalbox-description">
                            <h4 style="color:#000000 !important;"><strong><?php the_field('Namn'); ?></strong></h4>
                            <h6 style="color:#000000 !important;;"><?php the_field('title'); ?></h6>
                            <br>
                            <a href="tel:<?php the_field('telefon'); ?>"><h6 style="color:#000000 !important;"><strong>Telefon:</strong> <?php the_field('telefon'); ?></h6></a>
                            <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('e-post'); ?>"><h6 style="color:#000000 !important;"><strong>Mailt:</strong> <?php the_field('e-post'); ?></h6></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                </div>
<?php 
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is not my actual code, but a collegue. Thanks for your input, but it doesnt answer the question.

Comment: Have you looked at `the_field('title')` value? I think you want to use the `get_` method of that.

Comment: So there’s No easy way of saying to show ”if title = CEO” then show, if not then dont?